# Missing Authorization header Spring Boot CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I'm developing an application using Spring Boot on backend and React on frontend. I'm having some issues with CORS and authorization: in particular, when I make a request from the frontend I put the `Authorization` header which contains the JWT token for authentication. Here an example from the code:

```
async function getUserInfo (username) {
const url = baseURL + "/users/" + username
const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('token')

let [err, response] = await to(fetch(url), {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

...

}
```

When the request arrives to the backend, this header is missing and authentication fails. To configure CORS on Spring Boot, I use the `@CrossOrigin` annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["*"], allowedHeaders = ["*"], exposedHeaders = ["*"])
@RestController
class UserController (
    val userDetailsService: UserDetailsServiceImpl,
    val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    val jwtUtils: JwtUtils
) {
 
...
 
}
```

The Security configuration is the following:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    //csrf is enable by default
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/users/{username}/**")
        .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .hasAuthority("CUSTOMER")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()

    http.addFilterBefore(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(jwtUtils),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
}
```

The requests are made using an ADMIN user on the endpoint `/users/{username}`, as shown in the frontend code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For starters inspect the actual request in your browser dev tools network. Is the Auth header included there?

Comment: Not sure where `to()` comes from but looks like you are setting the headers outside the `fetch()` call which seems strange. Shouldn't it be `to(fetch(url, options))`?

Comment: Hi, you're right, I make a mistake with parentheses. Now it works! The `to(...)` comes from `await-to-js` library, which helps the error handling of async calls.